# Choosing a specific column or cell for data to be entered into?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, time, timestamp

The script below places a static time stamp into column A whenever column B is edited.

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if (s.getName() == "Sheet1") { 
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getColumn() == 2) {
            var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);
            if (nextCell.getValue() === '')
                nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would like the timestamp to occur when columns B,C,D,E, etc. are edited.

How do I specify that Column A (or 1) is where I want the date to be placed?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation knows a Method on a Sheet [`getRange(row, column)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))

So I guess, this should work:

```
var firstCell = s.getRange(r.getRow(), 1);
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my answer. I have never done anything with app script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to get information about the cell that was edited. No need to use `getActiveSheet`, `getActiveCell` and `offset`:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range; // Range that was edited
  var sheet = range.getSheet(); // Sheet that was edited
  var editedRow = range.getRow(); // Row that was edited
  var editedCol = range.getColumn(); // Column that was edited
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && editedCol > 1) { // Check that edited sheet is "Sheet1" and edited column is not A
    var colA = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 1); // Get corresponding cell in column A
    if (colA.getValue() === "") colA.setValue(new Date()); // Set date if cell is empty
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Event objects: onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Sheet.getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)